# Batch File to xcopy multiple files from web server to share drive

Tags: batch, xcopy, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to copy a group of files from a folder on my SharePoint site to a network share folder for manipulation "off-line".  I am new to xcopy and batch files so trying to teach myself with Google!  Please help.  I suspect there is a problem with my syntax somewhere.  When I run the batch file it just loops over and over and never stops until I terminate it manually.

xcopy \"https://website.com/org/CCC/CCC Docs/CRQ/Daily Reports/" \"shareservername\CSRDs\Report Macros\"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **xcopy** to download from a HTTP url.

Here is a good utility for copying a website from its URL: http://www.httrack.com/
Here is wget which runs from command line: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: is there another batch file method of completing this?

Comment: First of all: Do you have other way for accesing the websites file? Is it your web site or someone else?

Comment: it's my site.  I am able to map a network drive to the web folder and have full read/write permissions.

Comment: Then you can use xcopy but you have to point source path to the actual path in the server, where the document root is. The actual place in the HDD where your website files are.